# How to store and re-use values of every printed element in a foreach construct PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am currently writing a textbased game in php and i just encountered a complication that I really want to solve somehow. I tried to search for solutions but without any success. This is my problem:

Im using a foreach to print out all the items in an array where the element value is greater than 0 (i dont want to show the items the user have 0 of).

BUT i cant figure out how to make each and every number input window and submit button printed unique (together) so that when the player clicks "sell" its sells the right item and the right amount of it! Right now it seems like i can only access the amount of the last element that the player want to sell.

**So my question is: How to store and re-use values of every printed element in a foreach construct?**

Se below:

```
if (loggedIn()) { ?>


<h3><center>Your items</center></h3><hr><br />
<div class=tools>
<table class="inventory">
<?php
foreach (array_slice($items, 2) as $key => $value) {

    if($value>0){

        echo    "<tr><form action='store.php' method='GET'> 
                    <td>".$key."</td>
                    <td>".$value."</td>
                    <td>st</td>
                    <td><input type='number' name='".$key."' value='0'></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' value='sell'></td>
                </form></tr>";
                }
}

  if(isset($_GET['Sell'])){
         echo $_GET[$key];
         // Here i want to decrease the value of given $key
       }

?>
   </table>
</div>
<?php

}else {

header('Location: index.php');

}
```

Comment: Why are you building a form for every one? build the form outside the loop and just display table elements within, then on submit have it determine which element was clicked

Comment: @clearshot66 Thanks for the fast response! I had it working before using switch statement and having the form opening and closing tag outside the statement but i wanted to shrink the code and now when i have the form outside the foreach construct i get this $_get URL: store.php?Såg=0&Skruvdragare=0&Sandpapper=0&Fogmassa=0&Lim=0&Arbetsskor=0&Sell=Sälj&Isolering=0&Markduk=0&Våtrumsgips=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is put one form around your table, and use a button element to indicate which item is being sold. All of the text inputs will be submitted, but only the button that was clicked will be submitted, so you can use the value of that button to get the correct text input. Like this:

```
<form action='store.php' method='GET'>
<table class="inventory">
<?php
foreach (array_slice($items, 2) as $key => $value) {
    if ($value > 0) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>$key</td>
                <td>$value</td>
                <td>st</td>
                <td><input type='number' name='items[$key]' value='0'></td>
                <td><button type='submit' name='item' value='$key'>sell</button></td>
              </tr>";
    }
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

Then you can get the item sold (which button was clicked):

```
$item_sold = $_GET['item'];
```

and use that to get the quantity

```
$number_sold = $_GET['items'][$item_sold];
```

---

I would recommend using POST rather than GET for this, since I assume it will make a change on your server.